# Assigning array() before using a variable like array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to find a proper and explanatory title but I couldn't and I will try to explain what I am asking here:

Normally if you don't assign an empty array to a variable, you can start assign values to indexes like this:

```
$hello["world"] = "Hello World";
...
echo $hello["world"];
```

but I always encounter such definition:

```
$hello = array() //assigning an empty array first
$hello["hello"] = "World";
...
echo $hello["hello"];
```

Why is it used a lot. Is there a performance gain or something with the second one?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh god, is the first really valid? I'm always discovering new reasons to hate PHP...

Comment: Yeah, as long as PHP engine the indexes, it interprets it as arrays. You don't have to use array() to declare something is array.

Comment: The latter is a good practice, it prevents another coder from guessing *OK so may be $hello is declared somewhere else, may be in another file*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two reasons:

- Better readability (you know the array is initialized at this point)
- Security - when running on a system with `register_globals` enabled a user could add e.g. `hello[moo]=something` to the query string and the array would already be initialized with this. `$hello = array();` overwrites this value though since a new array is created.

Answer (score 4):

Initializing your variables is *good practice*.
Take for example this:

```
$foo = 'bar';

// 10 lines and 1 year later
$foo['baz'] = 'test';
```

Congratulations, you now have the string `"tar"`.

This may happen accidentally and introduce needless bugs. It gets even worse with conditional variable creation. It's avoided easily by getting into the good habit of explicitly initializing your variables.

Answer (score 3):

```
$hello = array();

if(someConditionIsTrue){
    $hello["world"] = "Hello World";
}

foreach($hello as $val){     // this will not give you any error or warning.
   echo $val;     
}
```

But

```
if(someConditionIsTrue){
    $hello["world"] = "Hello World";
}

foreach($hello as $val){     // this will give you error .
   echo $val;     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the first one will produce a warning by PHP if you have `error_reporting` as `E_ALL`. You should always use the second method because it explicitly initialises a new array. If you are looking through code and out of nowhere see `$hello["hello"]` but cannot recall seeing any reference to `$hello` before, it would be confusing.

The same will happen if you do `$hello[] = "World"`, a warning will be displayed